# Idris Nat literals in types

Tags: idris

I'd like Idris to prove that `testMult : mult 3 3 = 9` is inhabited.

Unfortunately this is typed as

```
mult (fromInteger 3) (fromInteger 3) = fromInteger 9 : Type
```

I can work around it like this:

```
n3 : Nat; n3 = 3
n9 : Nat; n9 = 9
testMult : mult n3 n3 = n9
testMult = Refl
```

Is there a way to do something that would be similar to `mult (3 : Nat) (3 : Nat) = (9 : Nat)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function `the : (a : Type) -> a -> a` to specify the type when the type inference is failing for you.

```
testMult : the Nat (3 * 3) = the Nat 9
testMult = Refl
```

Note that you need to have `the` at both sides of the equality because Idris has heterogenous equality, that is, `(=) : {a : Type} -> {b : Type} -> a -> b -> Type`.

Alternatively, you could write

```
testMult : the Nat 3 * the Nat 3 = the Nat 9
testMult = Refl
```

If you prefer that style.